# use loader before matching any route for context global store?

Tags: remix.run

In a regular React App I'd use Redux to manage the state, where I'd dispatch the initial data before matching any route in `App`, however, Redux is not advised in Remix, so I'm using `useContext` instead.

Is there a way to call loaders to fetch initial data (e.g. session, objects, etc.) before/without having to match any route and to then store that data in the `context` global store and then can be accessed by any component whithin the store? That way, the API will only be called during app initialization.

I'm at this moment calling the initial data in the loader of `root.tsx`, getting it with `useLoaderData` and then passing it as a prop to `StoreProvider` to dispatch it in the global state, however, I don't think this should be done like that way.

```js
    export let loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }) => {
      let user = await getUser(request);
      const products = await db.product.findMany();
      return { user: user?.username, products };
    };
    
    function App() {
      const data = useLoaderData<LoaderData>();
    
      return (
        <html lang="en">
          ...
          <StoreProvider initData={data}>
            <body>
              ...
              <Outlet />
              <ScrollRestoration />
              <Scripts />
              {process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" && <LiveReload />}
            </body>
          </StoreProvider>
        </html>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: If I get it correctly you can get the data from root or any other "layout" "above" the current route via [useMatches](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1.1.3/api/remix#usematches), also you can now pass a context to [`<Outlet/>`](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1.1.3/api/remix#outlet-context-) and consume it via [`useOutletContext`](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1.1.3/api/remix#useoutletcontext), on another thought you can import the `loader` function from other routes just like any other JS function and call it wherever you need, just pass in the required arguments

Comment: Uh and there's also [`useLoaderData`](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1.1.3/api/remix#useloaderdata). Hope any of that helps, if not let me know please

Comment: Thanks. By accessing `loader` data from other components am I not causing a double fetch? I mean, lets say a parent route `/products` has this loader which makes some api calls, and I use this same loader in `/products/new/$id`, that wouldn't mean fetching twice? What I'm basically trying to do is to get some data when initializing the app and storing it in the `Context.Provider` so the child components don't have to use a loader for all this data everytime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think doing the data loading on the root route loader is the best way.

If you don't like that approach you could also fetch on entry.server and entry.client.

For example in entry.client you probably have something like this:

```
import { hydrate } from "react-dom";
import { RemixBrowser } from "remix";

hydrate(<RemixBrowser />, document);
```

So you can change it to do the fetch before calling hydrate.

```
import { hydrate } from "react-dom";
import { RemixBrowser } from "remix";

fetch(YOUR_API_ENDPOINT)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    hydrate(
      <YourContextProvider value={data}>
        <RemixBrowser />
      </YourContextProvider>,
      document
    )
  });
```

And in entry.server you can change the handleRequest function to something like this:

```
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import { RemixServer } from "remix";
import type { EntryContext } from "remix";

export default async function handleRequest(
  request: Request,
  responseStatusCode: number,
  responseHeaders: Headers,
  remixContext: EntryContext
) {
  let response = await fetch(YOUR_API_ENDPOINT)
  let data = await response.json()

  let markup = renderToString(
    <YourContextProvider value={data}>
      <RemixServer context={remixContext} url={request.url} />
    </YourContextProvider>
  );

  responseHeaders.set("Content-Type", "text/html");

  return new Response("<!DOCTYPE html>" + markup, {
    status: responseStatusCode,
    headers: responseHeaders
  });
}
```

By doing it on entry.client and entry.server the fetch will only happen once and it will never be triggered again.

---

I still recommend you to do it inside the loader of the root so after an action it can be fetched again to keep the data updated.

Comment: Interesting. Why are we doing this in both `entry.client` and in `entry.server`?

Comment: Because the fetch happens outside Remix loaders, you need to fetch server side to provide data to your context for the SSR and then fetch again (or somehow share the data) client side to provide the same data again. This is another reason why using a loader is better, you don’t need to care about this.

Comment: But fetching in -lets say- `root.tsx`, would make loader to fetch everytime the user goes into `/`. So I suppose that fetching twice is better than fetching every navigation to `/`.

Comment: It will not, Remix doesn’t fetch a loader or already has data for when doing a navigation, only after a form submission, the root is also not only used for / but for every route. Again it will be called in the first request of the app and then after a form submission

Comment: I was adding a `console.log` to the root loader and it was being invoked any time I was navigating to root so I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: The render happens at any time yeah, that’s React, but the fetch doesn’t, useLoaderData is not doing running the loader  just accessing the data